# Dynamic Code Evolution Vm - For Ejb Jar Deployment

Tags: jboss, ejb, dcevm

I'm working on EJB 3.0 with Jboss 6.1 at the moment. All the time after I change someshing in EJB modules (server side) I have to export JAR file to /jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy

it's very uncomortable. I know that DCEVM can make that automatically. I've just install Dynamic Code Evolution VM but now I dont undestand what should I do now? Do I need any DCEVM plugin for Eclipse?

this is my Screen, i use Ubuntu 12.04:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixcku.png

Comment: You `don't need` any plugin for DCEVM plugin for Eclipse, as DCEVM is a modification of the VM itself.  Hence, Eclipse (or any tool for that matter) has no idea whether it is using a normal JVM or a DCEVM-installed-JVM.  Just ensure you are using the same patched JRE for both launching Eclipse and the application server.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find instructions:

http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2012/02/02/spring-mvc-velocity-dcevm/